# Trouble setting up the simulator for Xcode via my MacOS for Flutter on VS Code

Tags: flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

I keep getting an error when I try to set up the simulator for Xcode. I had to update my Mac OS software to install the Xcode, but when I try to open the simulator via the Command. I'm sorry, I would upload the screenshot, but SOF says the image is too large to upload

This is the error message.

Simulator cannot launch due to missing dependencies.

Simulator requires additional components, but installation failed because Xcode's license has not been agreed to.  Please launch Xcode to view the license agreement and complete installation.

Comment: instead screenshot the whole screen, do cmd + shift + 4, and you can select the area you want to screenshot, so that it will be smaller.

Comment: Yeah I got the simulator open via Xcode on my MacOS. But if you could help me with installing Git for version control on VS Code, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just opened another Flutter project on VS Code. But I'm having another issue, and that is source control on VSC. I'm trying to create a repo Github for my new Flutter project by connecting it.

Also it would be nice if I could create a Flutter project on IntelliJ. But I'm having trouble with auto import

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).